# ToC fine, but wrong hierarchical structure of index

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, sv-classes

I'm using [Springer's *svmult* template](http://www.springer.com/authors/book+authors?SGWID=1-154102-12-427299-0) for an edited book.

The header of each article inside the book looks like this:

```
\title{Article's Title}
\author{Author's Name}
\institute{\texttt{author@email.com}}
\maketitle
```

The Table of Contents (ToC) of the book looks fine, with

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
```

but the *index* (the document tree-structure seen at the left-hand side in a PDF viewer) has the wrong hierarchical structure and includes the author names as book section, more or less like this:

```
I part 1
   1 chapter 1
       Author Name
          section 1
             subsection 1
             subsection 2
          section 2
              subsection 1
              subsection 2
       II part 2
          2 chapter 2
             Author Name
                section 1
                ...
             III part 3
                 3 chapter 3
                    Author Name
                       section 1
                       ....
```

So everything is nested inside part 1, the author name is considered as a section, and the following part 2 (e.g.) is nested inside this 'author name' section.  Clearly wrong.

Is that a known problem with *svmult*? When I download the template-folder and compile the sample *editor.tex* file, my PDF viewer does not show an index at all for the resulting PDF.

Or did I mess up something myself? What might be the cause of the problem?

**EDIT:**

Here is a minimal example that shows the described symptoms:

```
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file editor.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% sample root file for a complete "contributed book"
%
% "contributed book"
%
% Copy it to a new file with a new name and
% use it as a template for your own input.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Springer-Verlag %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\documentclass{svmult}
% \documentclass[parskip=full]{svmult}

% choose options for [] as required from the list
% in the Reference Guide, Sect. 2.2

\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{parskip}
% \usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{url}
% etc.
% see the list of further useful packages
% in the Reference Guide, Sects. 2.3, 3.1-3.3

\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                       % please use the style sprmidx.sty with
                       % your makeindex program

% depth table of content
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
% more space between section numbers and headlines in toc
\addtolength\tocsecnum{2ex}
\addtolength\tocsubsecnum{2ex}
\addtolength\tocsubsubsecnum{2ex}
\calctocindent


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

% \pagestyle{empty}
% \include{frontmatter/titlepage} 


%%-- TEMPLATE FOR SECTIONS ----------------------


\frontmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% \include{frontmatter/dedic}
% \include{frontmatter/pref}

\tableofcontents

% \include{frontmatter/cblist}

\mainmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\part{Part 1}

\title{Article 1}
\author{Author 1}
\institute{\texttt{author1@email.com}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
  ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
  aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
  pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
  culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{abstract}

\section{Section 1.1}
\label{sec:1.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\section{Section 1.2}
\label{sec:1.2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\subsection{Subsection 1.2.1}
\label{sec:1.2.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\title{Article 2}
\author{Author 2}
\institute{\texttt{author2@email.com}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
  ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
  aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
  pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
  culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{abstract}

\section{Section 2.1}
\label{sec:2.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\section{Section 2.2}
\label{sec:2.2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\subsection{Subsection 2.2.1}
\label{sec:2.2.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\part{Part 2}

\title{Article 3}
\author{Author 3}
\institute{\texttt{author3@email.com}}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
  ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
  aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
  pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
  culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{abstract}

\section{Section 3.1}
\label{sec:3.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\section{Section 3.2}
\label{sec:3.2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\subsection{Subsection 3.2.1}
\label{sec:3.2.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\title{Article 4}
\author{Author 4}
\institute{\texttt{author4@email.com}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
  ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
  aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
  pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
  culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{abstract}

\section{Section 4.1}
\label{sec:4.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\section{Section 4.2}
\label{sec:4.2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\subsection{Subsection 4.4.1}
\label{sec:4.2.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\part{Part 3}

\title{Article 5}
\author{Author 5}
\institute{\texttt{author5@email.com}}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
  ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
  aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
  pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
  culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{abstract}

\section{Section 5.1}
\label{sec:5.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\section{Section 5.2}
\label{sec:5.2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\subsection{Subsection 5.2.1}
\label{sec:5.2.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\title{Article 6}
\author{Author 6}
\institute{\texttt{author6@email.com}}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
  ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
  aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
  pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
  culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{abstract}

\section{Section 6.1}
\label{sec:6.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\section{Section 6.2}
\label{sec:6.2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\subsection{Subsection 6.6.1}
\label{sec:6.2.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\backmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%#
\appendix
% \include{backmatter/appendix}
\printindex

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Using package *bookmark* (almost) solves the problem, only when there are two authors for an article there are still problems. 
Replace

```
\title{Article 1}
\author{Author 1}
\institute{\texttt{author1@email.com}}
```

in the MWE above with

```
\title{Article 1}
\author{Marco Author1 \inst{1}\and
Jos\'{e} Author2 \inst{2}}
\institute{
\texttt{author1@email.com}
\and \texttt{author2@email.com}}
```

and there is an error message:

```
ERROR: Missing \endcsname inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname
l.83 

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
```

and it looks strange in the pdf index:

```
Marco Author1 cl@@auth and Jose Author2
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The algorithm of `hyperref` for the bookmarks (outlines) requires unique destination names.
That is not the case for author bookmarks, they use the same destination as the article.

Because of this limitation I had written package `bookmark` that does not rely on unique
destination names. (Also less compile runs are needed and other actions are supported.)

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
```

**Update** for two authors. `\and` is not expandable and breaks in bookmarks.
The following replaces `\and` with a comma in the bookmarks.

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\and{, }}
```

Alternatively `\texorpdfstring` can be used.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfect for articles with single authors. When there are 2 authors, I still get errors (see edited question above)

Comment: Thanks again, now everything looks fine, great. Hard to imagine how a non-expert in LaTeX could come up with solutions like that - what makes your help even more valuable.